# C# - Game Server/Client - How to implement Friend status (i.e online, in game)

Tags: c#, sql, client-server

I have build a client app and app server app that can be used by players to play a card game. My current setup is as follows:

1)

- Client Login .
- Server is connected to an sql.
- Server saves the connection ("receiver") to a list
  ("ReceiverList").
- Server has an Event Class ("eventHolder"). Client connect/disconnect/request to queue/join Game.
- Server has a Game Class which is instantiate after 4 players queue. The active Game Classes are stored in a GameList
- Server runs on 4 threads:
  a) 2 Threads to run each receiver in ReceiverList to send and receive messages
  b) 1 Thread for queue.
  c) 1 Thread to run each game in GameList.

The problem i have is that i am not sure how to implement Friends Class. 
Assume Client A is friend with Client B. If Client B comes online i need to sent message to Client A that Client B has come online (or "In game", or "Disconnected").

What is the best way to do that? Through the events? for example if a client log in search each client if they have that username in there friend list? i even saw some recommendations to keep the online player in an SQL table and request online player for each receiver every 5 seconds which i dont think is optimal.

Answer (score -1):

Background process which begins with gaming being on . doesnt use a lot of system resources keeps checking for logged in user and present users in thier relationship . this is my opinion but you can have a thread run seperately